# EA_OnContextItemChanged for multi-selection

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I use Geert Bellekens' template in order to create Sparx Enterprise Architect Add-Ins, but the question should be valid for the API in general. EA_OnContextItemChanged does not react to selection of multiple items. What would be an appropriate way to react to such multi-selections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the event is called on selection of multiple items as well, however it is called only **once** when you select multiple items, not for each item individually.

So once the event has been called you can use `Repository.GetTreeSelectedElements()` to get the set of elements selected in the project browser, or `Diagram.SelectedObjects()` to get those selected on a diagram.

Comment: Don't know why it didn't fire yesterday, but you are right. And Diagram.SelectedObjects is way to go for me. Thanks!